# GitHub Objective-C SDK for accessing GitHub API from iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, sdk

I was trying to find some already existing Objective-C library / SDK to communicate with GitHub repositories (browsing / posting issues, etc...) from iPhone. I am very much surprised I did not find anything.

Are there any nice Objective-C framework / kit (like facebook-ios-sdk for instance)  or do I have to develop everything by myself from scratch (together with OAuth authorization, etc...)?

Comment: None of the answers are satisfying. UAGithubEngine does not provide the feature which was the most important for me: OAuth authorization flow (access_token generation). And I have not found any ready reliable GitHub API client in Objective-C which would support that. I ended up developing my own.

Comment: That's what I said you should do in the comments section of my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use an OAuth client, you just need to store the access token provided to you by the service.

There actually is a wrapper for the Github API: https://github.com/owainhunt/UAGithubEngine.

Make sure that you search around before posting.

Comment: From the readme file: " `api3` branch is currently *exceedingly* incomplete, unstable, unfinished, non-worky, half-missing," - and api3 is the only version allowing Oauth authentication.

Comment: So then the answer is Yes, develop your own.

Comment: UAGithubEngine does not support OAuth flow (access_token). My question specifically was mentioning that. You need to provide your user name and password to the API.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because of max_s comment as I ended up developing my own.

Comment: Hi Lukasz , would you mind sharing your work as an open source or do I need to start from scratch :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/)**.It works good for me

you can use it to search and install library

and it make your project clean